# How to use a database value in manifest.json

Tags: reactjs, symfony, manifest

The project uses Symfony 4 and React.

In the project, there is two folders :

- **api** for Symfony
- **client** for React

So, there is two **public** directories. One into **api** and another one into **client**.

The entrypoint of application is the index.html in **client/public**. At this place I declare the manifest.json :

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000">
    <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="max-age=0" />
    <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" />
    <meta http-equiv="expires" content="0" />
    <meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />
    <!--
      manifest.json provides metadata used when your web app is added to the
      homescreen on Android. See https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/engage-and-retain/web-app-manifest/
    -->
    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico">
    <!--
      Notice the use of %PUBLIC_URL% in the tags above.
      It will be replaced with the URL of the `public` folder during the build.
      Only files inside the `public` folder can be referenced from the HTML.

      Unlike "/favicon.ico" or "favicon.ico", "%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" will
      work correctly both with client-side routing and a non-root public URL.
      Learn how to configure a non-root public URL by running `npm run build`.
    -->
    <title>DFP</title>
  </head>
  <body class="">
    <noscript>
      You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.
    </noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <div id="popupContainer"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

The application has a backoffice where we could define the logo. This logo is saved in **api/public** folder.

I would like to retrieve this logo for using it as icon. So using **api/public** (symfony) data from **client** (react) folder.

I tried to create a Symfony route but she's not accessible maybe because the application uses React route. I tried when data are persisted in database to create the file in **client/public** directory but not working too.
What could I do to achieve this ?

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

Serve `manifest.json` with Symfony controller.
Add to `routes.yaml` file

```
manifest.json:
    path: /manifest.json
    controller: App\Controller\ManifestController::index
```

and create manifest controller, something like

```
<?php
namespace App\Controller;


use App\Entity\Config;
use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ManagerRegistry;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;

class ManifestController
{

    private $doctrine;

    public function __construct(ManagerRegistry $doctrine)
    {
        $this->doctrine = $doctrine;
    }


    public function index(): JsonResponse
    {

        $bgColor = '#fff';
        $config = $this->doctrine->getManagerForClass(Config::class)
            ->getRepository(Config::class)
            ->findOneBy(['type' => 'background_color']);
        if ($config) {
            $bgColor = $config->getValue();
        }

        $manifest = [
            "name" => 'Example.com',
            "gcm_user_visible_only" => true,
            "short_name" => 'Example',
            "description" => 'Some example description',
            "start_url" => "/index.php",
            "display" => "standalone",
            "orientation" => "portrait",
            "background_color" => $bgColor,
            "theme_color" => "#f0f0f0",
            "icons" => [
                "src" => "logo-load.png",
                "sizes" => "96x96 128x128 144x144",
                "type" => "image/png"
            ],
            "src" => "logo-icon.png",
            "sizes" => "48x48 72x72",
            "type" => "image/png"
        ];

        return new JsonResponse($manifest);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, this could work but my issue is to access the route created on Symfony side in the ReactJS side. Routes created via Symfony are like **localhost-static** so in index.html this doesn't work : `<link rel="manifest" href="/manifest">` because this is looking at `localhost/manifest` instead of `localhost-static/manifest`

Comment: `<link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json">` is link as any and you can serve it from another domain, in your case from 
 `<link rel="manifest" href="http://localhost-static/manifest">`. Hopefully brausers also accept that ;) but you can check that with Chrome Dev Tools Audits.

Comment: This doesn't works. In index.html (which is on localhost domain) I did this `<link rel="manifest" href="/manifest">`. Then Symfony side (which is localhost-static domain) I added the route `manifest.json:
    path: /manifest
    controller: App\Controller\ApiController::createManifestJson` then in ApiController I create the response like you. When I'm looking in Dev debug on chrome the manifest request URL is `https://localhost/manifest`

Comment: Tried out myself - yes browser does not fetch manifest from another host. Then you must set up a proxy in your app server that itself fetches info from another host.
Sry for the late response. Hope you still can make use of it.